# Yii2 conditional model

Tags: yii2

I've a problem with a form developed in yii2. I've set a field of form as interger and I've connected it into an attribute of another models.

I wish I could leave it blank, or enter the correct values, but if I leave empty value I get an error.

```
public function rules() {
  return [
    [['id_user'], 'integer', 'message' => ERROR_INTEGER],
    [['id_user'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['id_user' => 'id']],
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using  `'skipOnEmpty' => true,`

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['id_user'], 'integer', 'message' => ERROR_INTEGER],
        [['id_user'], 'exist', 
            'skipOnError' => true, 
            'skipOnEmpty' => true,
            'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['id_user' => 'id']
        ],
   ];
}
```